# Is it possible to implement a cachebreaker at the end of an api endpoint in order to reload an jpeg in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a component using React. This component contains an  tag, whose source is an url that gives a jpeg as content-type. This api endpoint, who gives the jpeg back, takes a new shot every minute.
My goal is to update the src every minute, and after every update I can display the new shot.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import './App.css';



function ImageDisplayer() {
  const [clockState, setClockState] = useState(new Date())
  
  const keyMinute = useRef(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const clock = window.setInterval(() => {
      setClockState(new Date())
    }, 1000)  
    return () => window.clearInterval(clock)
  }, [])  

  useEffect(() => {

    let image = document.getElementById('changing-pic')
    image.src = 'http://serverwithapi.com/api/image/2'

  },[keyMinute.current])

  if (clockState.getSeconds() === 4){
    keyMinute.current = clockState.getMinutes()
  }

  return (
    <div>
     <img id ='changing-pic' alt='Pic' style={{width:'40vw'}}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course, it didn't work. I think the reason is because there is no change in the `image.src` so I tried to implement a 'cachebreaker' in order to change the string like this:

```
//inside the useEffect 

let timestamp = new Date().getTime();
let image = document.getElementById('changing-pic')
image.src = 'http://serverwithapi.com/api/image/2?' + timestamp
```

As I expected, that didn't work. I saw examples where they were showing how to fool the cache but with .jpeg or .png files. For example here:
https://instructobit.com/tutorial/119/Force-an-image-to-reload-and-refresh-using-Javascript

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the update even though I am using an api endpoint. Is there a workaround for this? I would be very thankful

I can't use Axios or fetch on the client side because I don't have access to the server and when I use them I get a CORS error. I can't use a proxy server to avoid the CORS error because this server won't have access to the internet, so it can't reach the endpoint. The client itself has to display the image.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Did you mean to just append the timestamp to the end of the url or was it a typo? You should be sending it as a query parameter by include a `?` between the two to fool the browser it is a new file ie `image.src = 'http://serverwithapi.com/api/image/2?' + timestamp` otherwise it looks like you're calling a timestamp url with a `2` prepended

Comment: Oh excuse me, it was a typo. I used a ? inbetween but it didn't work. I will edit the question. Thanks for the observation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just realized how to do it, if anyone is interested. The number 2 is part of the endpoint.

I tried this:

```
//inside the useEffect 

let timestamp = new Date().getTime();
let image = document.getElementById('changing-pic')
image.src = 'http://serverwithapi.com/api/image/2/?' + timestamp
```

And it worked! Notice the '/' between the 2 and the question mark, I didn't have it before.